# Pushing HTML page to one side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a sidebar to my Twitter Bootstrap 3 application. When I click a button, a fixed positioned `nav nav-pills nav-stacked` appears on the left side of my page. And I gave `z-index:1000`, so it appears on top of my content.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/8YtDS/14/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="/" title="">
        MyBrand
    </a>

    </div>
</nav>
<div class="col-md-3" id="mysidebar" style="  top: 0;bottom:0; left: 10px;
    position: fixed;     height: 100%;    background-color: #faff18;
    opacity: 0.9;    overflow: hidden;    z-index:1000;      margin: 0;  padding: 0; display:none;">
    <div style="position: relative;  top: 60px;  background-color: #7d1c80; opacity: 0.9;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color: #aaa;">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
        <button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        <button id="mybutton" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Click me to toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need different behaviour, when sidebar appears my page will be pushed to right side. Check this page and click top left button. How can I get this behaviour with css/js ?
http://jpanelmenu.com/

Comment: you can easily do this with jquery, with just the animate function

Comment: I want body content to be pushed one side. Not interested in animation.

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/

Comment: do you want to show "do something" menu on the right side ?

Comment: or something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/1/

Comment: @qwertmax when "do something" menu is opened. page content will be pushed right side.

Answer (score 2):

A general practice would be to add a class to either the `<body>` tag or a main wrapper called something like `navopened` on the button click.

Once the class is added, you then can target any element using the class, and move your 'entire' page with either positioning: `position:relative; right: -[nav width]px`

or transforms: `transform:  translate([nav width]px)`

Transforms have better performance, but less browser support.

CSS Example:

```
/* before, without body class added */

body #outsidewrapper{
  position:relative;
  right:0px;
}

/* after, when the click event adds the class to the body */

body.navopened #outsidewrapper{
  position:right:-300px;
}
```

Now, it's important to note that you shouldn't be moving the body tag itself, as it has potential to hide your nav. I would move an outer wrapper instead.

Comment: when ```body @ outsidewrapper``` is pushed to right side, scroolbar appears for 300px of the content. Should I add ```overflow:hdden``` to ignore that content ?

Comment: Ideally, you'd either have another wrapper with overflow hidden, or you'd have overflow-x hidden on the body.

Comment: Should I use another wrapper?

Comment: If you can, it would probably be the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I did a few play arounds, one with my code and one with your code.

edited your one...
http://jsfiddle.net/8YtDS/15/

My one (button placement is pore, but you get the picture) 
http://jsfiddle.net/e6JnT/1/

My one can toggle it in and out...

The main part's is having a wrapper around the part's you want to move around... which would be your code in your case, and then you just move that or resize that accordingly.

I did slide it left but you can do it with size so you don't miss anything.

So into the code.

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").animate({
        left: '200px' 
    });

    $("#mysidebar").animate({
        left: '0px' 
    });          
});
```

So I use the animate function in jQuery as it's the most versatile function to move an element around and making it look nice.

and all I'm doing is sliding the element to the left to 200px to make room for the menu, and the slide the element with an id of 'myslidebar' to '0px' to make it able to been seen.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/8YtDS/18/

Comment: In the first fiddle, note that navbar on top doesn't move.

Comment: @trante do you want it to move?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways to accomplish this.

1. Replace `position: fixed` with `float: left`.
   a. See http://jsfiddle.net/kdcTc/

   b. Without bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/5kPNd/

   Moving the sidebar to the top, makes the top navbar shift to the right as well. This does *not* work with bootstrap. It seems, there is some condition in the bootstrap navbar classes, which prevents the shift.

   The class `navbar-fixed-top` seems to pin the top navbar. Removing it allows the brand navbar to shift, but has other side effects too.
2. Move the main panel and the navbar to the right, using a `margin-left`
   See http://jsfiddle.net/7eEaB/2/

Comment: Note that navbar on top doesn't move.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

http://jsfiddle.net/8YtDS/17/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu-panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="">Do something</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Do something</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header"> 
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="/" title="">
                   MyBrand
                </a>
            </div>
            </nav>
        <button id="mybutton" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
background: #F90;
}

#menu-panel{
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: -100px;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
}

#wrapper.open{
margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**Javscript**

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Just a note from experience: avoid using jQuery animate to 'smooth' the slide. On certain browsers it was very jittery for me. CSS transforms should be used if possible, as I believe they are handled by GPU, jQuery as a fail safe (see Modernizr).

Hope that was of some help!

Thanks

Phil